# Commiting changes error on github desktop

Tags: git, github, npm, github-pages, github-for-mac

I am new to git/github so I don't exactly know what I'm doing. I am trying to publish a site on github. I followed directions on https://pages.github.com/ to create the new repository. I didn't know the exact git command so I just drag and dropped files I had into the new git repository. However, when I try to commit the files to the master branch, I see a bunch of red-coded errors in the changes panel like the one in the bottom. Also, I am running sass on my html files. I don't know if this is interfering with the commit.

Comment: Looks like a line-ending issue to me. Also I don't think you've pushed yet...

Comment: Huzzah! Add line endings https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2019

Comment: I’ll try and add my comment as an answer

Comment: Is there a way to add line endings to multiple files without me going into each and every file to add line endings? I am using node modules and there's hundreds of files I have to edit.

Comment: Don't commit `node_modules` folder.

Comment: If you're using a mac, open terminal and use echo: `echo >> folder-of-files/*`